# how to realise sequential animation which plays one time and stops at last frame? (via Animator)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a sprite "Score_off" which have to play animation clips of appearing/disapearing random generated number after pushing button. 
Cycle which a want to make is next:

1. After pushing button some code gets random number "Score" from array [0,1,2,3]
2. Sprite plays an animation of disapearing previous number. (One time)
3. Sprite plays an animation of apearing current number. (One time)
4. Animation stops at last frame which shows current number.

So, I have eight animation clips:
0_anim | 0_anim_reverse
...
3_anim | 3_anim_reverse.

"_reverse" clips are same animations with speed = -1.
All clips have disabled loop parameter.

I've created eight (bool)parameters for each state, links First animation with each animation in Animator and set Condition for each link.

Screenshot of Animator: 
https://sun9-26.userapi.com/c857636/v857636970/b542e/Et8GtY25Hi0.jpg

```
//some roll code
int score = GetRandomScore();
Score_off.GetComponent<AnimatorScore>().PlayAnimation(score, Score_off);

//Score_off script:
public class AnimatorScore : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string currentState = "First";

    IEnumerator Waiting()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    }

public void PlayAnimation(int animationToPlay, GameObject target)
    {
        Animator anim = target.GetComponent<Animator>();

        anim.SetBool(currentState, false); //remove bool of old anim

        if (currentState != "First")
        {
            currentState += "_reverse";
            anim.SetBool(currentState, true);  
        }

        StartCoroutine(Waiting());
        anim.SetBool(currentState, false); //disable previous anim

        currentState = animationToPlay.ToString() + "_anim";
        anim.SetBool(currentState, true); //play new anim
    }
}
```

This works uncorrectly - code disabling old animation, starts animation "First" on couple ms and plays correct current apeare animation, without playing disapearing animation. And when previous number is such as current - there is no animation.

Please, help me to choose correct way how to realise this animation scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Use the animation state machines.

Create an animation state that represents Idle (your last frame), and transition to it at the end of the Playing animation state. Specify the exit time in the transition as the length of the sequential animation you have made.